# Unable to append data into a nested list python

Tags: list, loops, append, nested-lists, index-error

```
  '''
distList = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.76333, -4.22504, -2.42978, 0.81744, 0.1], [-0.91351, -3.76965, -3.34161, -1.66984, 0.1], [-2.5362, 0.22098, -3.49264, -2.34982, 0.1]]
    sumList = []
    for i in range(len(distList)):
      for j in range(len(distList[i])):
        sumofNum =distList[i][j]*distList[i][j]
        sumList[i].append(sumofNum)
    '''
```

' getting error IndexError: list index out of range at last line '

Comment: ```range(len(distList)-1):``` ,```range(len(distList[i])-1)```change this

Comment: Hello, 
Just change last line from: sumList[i].append(sumofNum) to sumList.append(sumofNum). 
Python list don't need index while appending. for 'Insert' operation you need an index.

Comment: But I need to give index to create a nested list. sumList.append(sumofNum) creates a normal list

Answer (score 0):

```
sumList[i].append(sumofNum)
```

to

```
sumList.append(sumofNum)
```